# Accordion tab positioning to top on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have to position the clicked accordion tab (here Label) to top widow position so that i can read full tab contents on one click. I Know how to position using # or id if there is an a tag. But here is a label instead of a tag. my plugin is written in fully CSS3. So please help me to customize using javascript / jQuery. I am a beginner in jQuery. so please help. Thank you  .

```
<div>
   <label>Accordion Tab 1</label>
   <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
<div>
   <label>Accordion Tab 2</label>
   <div class="contents"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will jquery-ui tabs not help ? [jquery-ui tabs()](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: Could you show an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @Billy already all coding done so can not changed..

Comment: @ToX82 Reffer this link [link](http://www.maitriglobaleducation.com/institutes/polimoda/courses/)
. I had done this page using a tag. But Now I want the same effect usinf label or other tags.

Comment: You might want to edit the line in your question that says `So please help me to customize using javascript / jQuery`

Comment: @ToX82 Coz i already do some modification on tabs by appending arrows or some easing effect. You simply say the idea thats all. using jquery or css or javascript. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a (really simple) accordion you can build by yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/2savod3v/

```
$("label").on('click', function() {
    $("div.contents").slideUp();
    $(this).next("div.contents").slideDown(); 
});
```

Comment: But i want to position the clicked tab to top window position. That is what i want like in link.

Comment: Then you should tell the browser to move your viewport there like this (it will not really be moving to the top because there is too little content):  http://jsfiddle.net/2savod3v/1/
$(window).scrollTop(activeDiv.offset().top)

Comment: .I think now got the idea..Thank you so much :)